# Move mail to "Junk Email" folder and create a spam rule

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to move the selected email to the "Junk Email" folder and create a spam rule for that email address that automatically sends all future emails from that address to my junk email.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get some good responses and help, please show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a message, try something like the following (off the top of my head)

```
if Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
  set Folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
  set Msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
  Msg.Move(Folder)
End If
```

Outlook Object Model does not expose Junk mail settings. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDOJunkEmailOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdojunkemailoptions.htm).`BlockedSenders.Add` method.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, unfortunately it is not, but knowing there is not a solution is still an answer. Sorry for the delayed response.